# pasar variable dinamica a urlmatcher en angular

Tags: angular

En mi rutas angular uso urlmatcher, donde quiero validar si una variable pasada por url esta en un array, este lo tengo en estático pero me gustaría traerlo de una base de datos porque en un futuro podría cambiar, añadir o quitar. Angular no deja usar servicios para hacer esto.
Resolve tampoco es lo que necesito.
como debería hacerlo?

```
const products: string[] = [
  'smartphone',
  'tv',
  'pc',
  'games'
]

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    matcher: (url: UrlSegment[]): UrlMatchResult  => {
      let total = url.length;
      if(total === 3){
        if(products.includes(url[1].path)){
          return {
            consumed: url,
            posParams: {
              product: new UrlSegment(url[2].path, {}),
            }
        }
      }
    },
    
    component: productComponent
  }
]
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien todo el concepto al que quieres llegar. No digo que este mal lo que estés haciendo, simplemente no entiendo por que no he tenido la necesidad de trabajarlo así, pero se me ocurre que puedes usar axios desde otro script para sobrescribir `const products = []` de manera global. Al final, angular es typescript, y typescript compila a Javascript y como bien sabes, en javascript no hay respeto si tu mismo no se lo das, así que si, te lo puedes saltar. Es una posible solución. Otra recomendación es cambiar la arquitectura, pero depende de que es lo que quieres lograr.

Comment: Quiero crear url amigables, estas variables son filtros y uno de ellos me crea conflicto dependiendo de los filtros que seleccione el usuario, es decir la url puede tener 3 variables y es ahí cuando una de ellas puede coincidir con un filtro o otro. En fin el problema es porque son urls, ahora bien , estos filtros son los que el usuario usan constantemente por eso lo quiero de esta manera. también tengo mas filtros pero ahí ya uso parámetros del tipo nombre=valor porque no se usan tanto..

La solución de ajax esta bien pero quizás si no hay otra solución dejaría el array estático.

Comment: Por qué no usas un parámetro en la ruta: `products/:product` Y luego en el componente `productComponent` lo lees y validas si existe en el arreglo.

Comment: pongo ejemplo de url para que se entienda mejor, como digo son filtros algo asi: /categoria1/subcategoria1/categoria2/subcategoria2 pero son opcionales los filtros entonces podria quedar url como esta: categoria1/categoria2/subcategoria2 o categoria1/subcategoria1/categoria2 una solucion seria algo asi pero no me gusta : /categoria1/sinvalor/categoria2/subcategoria2